# Select a JList item which will display info to JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, jlist

I have two classes. A Book class which contains the title, author, and isbn. The second class is the driver class called Library.

The GUI contains a jlist and 3 text fields.
The jlist is an arraylist of items from the Book class (title, author, isbn).
When one item is selected from the jlist the text fields show the: title, author, and isbn of the item.

My problem is how do I have the selected jlist item display the info in the textfields? I just need someone to point me into the right direction, I'm trying to understand this logically and then implement it into code.

*The Jlist items contain: Book 1, Book 2, Book 3 so if I select Book 1 it will display Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, J.K. Rowling, 24325543.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JList, you can use `getSelectedIndex()` to get index of selected item or `getSelectedValue()` to get oject item.

Comment: Using this, is it advised to use the Iterator class or make a for loop to get the book title in one JTextField, the author in another, and so on?

Comment: When you had a selected object value, you can use this to access author, title... You don't need a for loop

Comment: I feel like I'm thinking too hard, how do I translate what you said to code? If I just want the author from the arraylist to go onto its JTextField I do `booksJList.getSelectedValue();` but how do I know it is accessing the author only?

Comment: `getSelectedValue()` will return a Book object in your case. Like `Book book = booksJList.getSelectedVaule()`. And you can access title by `book.title`. Make sure you declare your title field public. And so on with other filed.